# ORA-01722: The specified number was invalid when truncating timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Query:

```
SELECT
    first_load_time
FROM
    v$sql;
```

Result:

```
2017-02-16/07:45:25
2017-02-17/06:47:36
2017-02-17/02:05:31
2017-02-15/17:39:13
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    to_char(FIRST_LOAD_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
FROM
    v$sql;
```

Result:

> ORA-01722: *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.

```
SELECT
    trunc(FIRST_LOAD_TIME)
FROM
    v$sql;
```

> ORA-01722: *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.

Why does oracle give invalid number error when truncating the timestamp? I need to do a group by with date on this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FIRST_LOAD_TIME column is actually a VARCHAR2 (which is a bit strange to me) so;

```
select to_date(first_load_time,'YYYY-MM-DD/HH24:MI:SS') from v$sql
```

Will show it as a date by applying the function TO_DATE.
Simply add a TRUNC to the beginning to get the value you want;

```
select TRUNC(to_date(first_load_time,'YYYY-MM-DD/HH24:MI:SS')) from v$sql
```

Comment: Blimey! My love for Oracle just grows by the day

Comment: It is a strange one that's for sure.